# How to access a properties' get accessor of another instance within its class?

Tags: apex, class, getter

I have a simple class with a property and a parent that is of the same type.

```
public class BasicProperty {
   private BasicProperty parentProp;
   private Integer myCounter = 0;

   public Integer prop {
      get { this.myCounter++; return this.parentProp.prop; }
      set { prop = value; }
   }
}
```

In this example, `this.parentProp` will give us the value of the property, bypassing the get accessor.

Is it possible to access the value of the property of another instance using the accessor?

Of course, I could resolve this by using a wrapper method and calling it instead - but it makes the code harder to read and it's not immediately clear what is happening there in the first place.

Comment: Can you post the example you used to check this. I am not getting this behavior based on my check

Comment: I clarified the question and put in a counter to illustrate the difference between accessor vs. value.

Comment: Your property won't be valid you are returning BasicPropery type not integer

Comment: Whoops. Typo. It should be `return this.parentProp.prop` of course.

Comment: Saw your edit. I'd need to research, this is not in the docs.

Comment: The problem with this is you are going to see a infinite recursion. You will probably null reference out though since you have no null check. It should not bypass anything you are referencing something other that itself. This holds true against what @sfdcfox mentioned in his answer apex has a nice feature that allows you to self reference in property accessors and avoid recursion and a backing field to avoid the recursion.

Comment: Of course, this example is overly simplified without any checks or anything. The point is: If I'm not referencing myself - why does it still skip the accessor? I did not find anything in the docs.